# selenium-webdriver can't find the driver in javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

```
const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("selenium-webdriver/Firefox");
async function example(){
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('Firefox').build();
await driver.get("https://www.google.com");
await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium", Key.RETURN);
```

Hello,
I am constantly getting these errors, although I added the webdriver path in the system and I cant execute the test.
Has anyone experienced something like that?

```
(node:15844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Do not know how to build driver: Firefox
(node:4764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Builder is not a constructor
```

Comment: I think you must pass in `firefox` instead of `Firefox`

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error "TypeError: Builder.forBrowser is not a constructor" for a sample code from any tutorial. Turns out they miss parenthesis after `Builder`.
The correct code:

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

Comment: But the question has those parentheses... so this couldn't be the solution.

Comment: for me I forgot parentheses so this answer helped me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this :

```
const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
```

Comment: Hello, 
I tried both of the answers and i just get this:
node:17904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Do not know how to build driver: Firefox; did you forget to call usingServer(url)?